# Batman vs the truck driver, please explain

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

Batman wasn't supposed to kill anyone but during the climactic scene of *[The Dark Knight Rises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Rises)*,  he shoots the truck carrying the bomb with [The Bat](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bat) in an attempt to reroute the truck and the driver is killed.

Did Nolan make a mistake here?

Comment: a related question here:  http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/did-batman-break-his-one-rule

Comment: Well to put it in a more simple way, lives of whole city, approx. 1 million lives were in jeopardy, killing one or two terrorists didn't even worth Batman's "No Killing Rule".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even in The Dark Knight Batman tries to save Gordon's son and pushes Dent from the edge. But accidentally Dent dies. So Batman has his own rules saying not to kill anyone intentionally. In the same way he wanted to divert the truck by shooting but accidentally shoots the driver. So that doesn't mean Nolan as well as Batman makes a mistake.

It was an accident...

Comment: Batman must have known that the bullet may accidentally hit the driver or talia when he shoots. Even then he prefers to shoot.. That doesn't make any sense..

Comment: or may be he would have even knew that dent would die when he pushed him off the edge. But he chose to do that. Because to save his city he could some times break his rules.

Comment: Yet that scene with Dent at the end seems to be a very special case that had particular impact on the Batman, as explained in [this related question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2789/49) and its answers.