# In The Dark Knight, does the Joker know who Batman is?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-dark-knight

In the movie *The Dark Knight*, the Joker initially threatens that he would kill people everyday if Batman does not reveal his true identity.

But he also threatens Mr.Reese when he tries to unveil the true identity of Batman.

Why did he do so and what does he actually want?

Comment: That Joker... *he crazy*!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Does Joker know who Batman is?

Short answer: It doesn't matter.

Long answer: He might, he might not, but in Joker's mind it's much more fun to interact with **Batman**; interacting with the man behind the mask is boring.

A lot of Joker's motivation is explained in the answer to this question: [What did the Joker want to prove in The Dark Knight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15288/what-did-the-joker-want-to-prove-in-the-dark-knight?rq=1)

To paraphrase: Joker wants chaos. Threatening to kill people if Batman doesn't reveal himself isn't motivated by Joker wanting to know who Batman is, it's motivated by wanting to cause panic and chaos.

This is also why he stops Mr. Reese from revealing Batman's identity; Joker really doesn't want to know.

Comment: Ya totally agree.

Comment: plus, he didn't want reese to reveal it because joker wanted to do everything himself. even the revealing, if he wanted to do