# Are there any other Batman cartoons that are adapted directly from a comic?

Tags: batman-year-one

Last night I watched [Batman: Year One](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1672723/?ref_=nv_sr_1) and thought it was great. I'm not very knowledgable about the different Batman versions but I know that this one is part of Frank Miller's adaptations.

**Are there any other cartoons or films that are direct adaptations from Batman comics?** I don't mean simply an influence on but rather I'm looking for a direct adaptation as this one was.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Universe_Animated_Original_Movies) might be a start. I.e. *The Dark Knight Returns* 1 & 2.

Comment: Define "based"? Many Batman films are based on Frank Miller's works, first and foremost the [Nolan trilogy](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/761/49).

Comment: I guess what I really want is more of the same so more accurately would be "direct adaptations". I'm not interested in something that just has a few elements or is partially influenced by. With Batman: Year One, it took a comic book by Frank Miller and made it into a frame by frame cartoon version of the original. So that's more of what I'm looking for. I've updated the wording in my question to reflect this.

Comment: Well, in this case see my first comment. Yet, this smells a little of a recommendation question.

Comment: I can see how it comes across that way which is why I want to be careful in communicating that I'm not just asking "hey what Batman cartoons are cool like this one".

Comment: Well, it's still the same thing pretty much, no matter if the criterium is objective or not. But for now I chose to leave it be and see how the community thinks about it.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve the question? I tried changing it a little bit so that it doesn't come across as a recommendation question. I am specifically interested in Frank Miller adaptations but I don't really know how else to ask the question.

Comment: Well, I don't know. Noone has close-voted it anyway yet, so maybe it's fine.

Comment: Taking into account that there are probably just a few _direct adaptations_ I wouldn't see it as a recommendation question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes.

The Dark Knight Returns comic, also written by Miller, was [animated in two parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Dark_Knight_Returns_(film)) around 2013 and is quite good. TDKR stayed pretty true to the comic. Batman v Superman drew some inspiration from this, including Batman's suit, but TDKR was simply better than BvS.

In addition, The Killing Joke, by Alan Moore, was just [animated recently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Killing_Joke_(film)) but did not stay as true to the comic as TDKR, nor was it quite as well received. Miller was not involved in writing or animating The Killing Joke.

Comment: I think TKJ stayed true to the comic (even Wikipedia mentions that _the film received mixed reviews from critics and audiences, who praised it for its voice acting and faithfulness to the source material_), they only added the Batgirl prologue.

Comment: I just realized the best way to answer this was right on IMDb all along. By looking at the writing credits on [Frank Miller's profile](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0588340/?ref_=ttfc_fc_wr4), there is clarification to whether he was an actual writer, creator of character's, or wrote the comic or graphic novel for different adaptations of his work.